# Is it possible to run QuestDB on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, questdb

I would like to run QuestDB on Raspberry Pi for time series data coming from sensors but it seems there is a problem with arm64. Is there a way I can build and run on RPi from source? I can't find anything for arm on https://hub.docker.com/r/questdb/questdb/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: look at https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/569

Comment: docker supports arm, it's up to the project to provide builds for it. Look at the above issue to see progress on this

Comment: can confirm docker now has arm64 builds that run great on a pi

Answer (score 0):

TickTock (https://github.com/ytyou/ticktock/) is a lightweight TSDB and can run in RPi zero wireless (32bit). You may give it a try.

Disclaimer: I am co-author of TickTock and it is still being stress test and not production ready yet.